# Show specific offers - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got a problem with showing specific offers on my website. This code should show only offers from user, whoose id is in url (http://mypage.pl/showall/{$id}). When I'm trying it, it shows page without single offer.

Controller:

```
        public function getViewUsers($id)
{
    $user = Sentry::getUser();
    $bikecreate = Bike::find($id);
    $bikes = Bike::where($bikecreate->users_id == $user->id);
    foreach (Province::all() as $value) {
        $prov[$value->id] = $value->name;
    }
    foreach (BikeType::all() as $value) {
        $type[$value->id] = $value->name;
    }
    return View::make('user.bikes.viewusers')->with('bike', $bikes)->with('province', $prov)->with('type', $type);
}
```

Route is here;

```
Route::get('bike/viewusers/{id}', array('as' => 'bike.viewusers', 'uses' => 'App\Controllers\User\BikeController@getViewUsers'));
```

Comment: @Gaz_Edge It is in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there may be several problems with the code....but the most obvious is this syntax:

```
$bikes = Bike::where($bikecreate->users_id == $user->id);
```

should be

```
$bikes = Bike::where('users_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
```

If I'm not mistaken, instead of these 3 lines of code:

```
$user = Sentry::getUser();
$bikecreate = Bike::find($id);
$bikes = Bike::where($bikecreate->users_id == $user->id);
```

What you mean to do is:

```
$bikes = Bike::where('users_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

[The proper syntax is available here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage)

Comment: @user3305675 I was only showing you your syntax error with the where() function, but your code logic seems to be way off what you want to do. You should first get the user by the $id from the URL, and then check for Bikes with that user_id using where().

Comment: I've done, what You showed me. I've also edited my route file. Now it looks like this: 'Route::get('bike/viewusers/{id}',  array('as' => 'bike.viewusers',      'uses' => 'App\Controllers\User\BikeController@getViewUsers'))->where('id', '[0-9]+');' But still nothing showed at the page.